# Firebase push very slow when inserting key that contains large arrays

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, firebase

Heyhou

I'm trying to add some 3D models (buildings) in JSON format to a Firebase from a Node.js server reading the data from a JSON file. I'm using the `push()` to add a key under `buildings`.

```
var buildingsRef = new Firebase('https://test.firebaseIO-demo.com/buildings');
buildingsRef.push({ ... });
```

Unfortunately, the push is very slow and it takes approx. 30 seconds to insert the JSON into Firebase. The JSON object looks like the following:

```
{
    geometries: {
        vertices: [...],
        faces: [...],
        normals: [....]
    },
    materials: {
    },
    object: {
    },
    metadata: {
    }
}
```

The geometries object contains Arrays for vertices, faces, normals, uv's, etc.. These arrays may have up to 10'000 entries or more, depending on the complexity of the 3D-Model.

I'm not sure if the large JSON itself (file on disk is about 2Mb) or the Array representation is the cause for the slow insertion into Firebase. I suspect  that it has something to do with how Firebase internally represents Arrays.

Is there any way to optimize this? I like to store the whole building under one key, so I can check in the frond end of my application if the building has been replaced (usually by the server-side). I don't need to modify the individual arrays, I just like to be able to swap out a building with a different one and let my front-end update accordingly.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you suspect that Firebase's array handling is the cause, you may want to test store the array as a regular string. So `vertices: "[ ...]"` instead of `vertices: [...]`. That way you'll bypass Firebase's array logic. For conversion, use `JSON.parse`/`JSON.stringify`.